# centos 6.4 64bit - yum : undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback

Tags: centos, yum

hi im having a bit of a problem with yum
any command i ask yum to do i get in return this error .
ive looked for a solution but i havent manged to find one yet.

badly need help

/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pycurl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback

Answer (score 1):

do an strace on the yum command, you'll probably see it pointing to the problem package or file...

```
open("/usr/lib/nsr/libcurl.so.4", O_RDONLY) = 9
```

do you have Networker installed? If so, uninstall it, remove all Networker RPM's and see if it is still broken.

nsr = Networker